# Why does music converted from .mp3 using mpg123 played by SFML stutter?

Tags: c++, c++17, sfml

I created a function that should play a .mp3 file by decoding it using mpg123 first and then play it using SFML.
The function:

```
void play_file(const std::string& filepath) {
    mpg123_init();
    mpg123_handle* mh = mpg123_new(NULL, NULL);

    if (mpg123_open(mh, filepath.c_str()) != MPG123_OK) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open file: " << filepath << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    long rate = 0;
    int channels = 0;
    int encoding = 0;
    mpg123_getformat(mh, &rate, &channels, &encoding);

    sf::SoundBuffer soundBuffer;
    std::vector<unsigned char> buffer(4096, 0); 

    size_t bytesRead = 0;
    while (mpg123_read(mh, buffer.data(), buffer.size(), &bytesRead) == MPG123_OK && bytesRead > 0) {
        
        soundBuffer.loadFromSamples(reinterpret_cast<const sf::Int16*>(buffer.data()), bytesRead / sizeof(sf::Int16), channels, rate);

        
        sf::Sound sound(soundBuffer);
        sound.play();

        
        while (sound.getStatus() == sf::Sound::Playing) {}
    }

    
    mpg123_close(mh);
    mpg123_delete(mh);
    mpg123_exit();
}
```

After some time, I discovered that if I put something like sleep_for into

```
while (sound.getStatus() == sf::Sound::Playing) {
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
}
```

the sound is stuttering every 1 second. So it has to be due to the while loop. However, I have not found out how to get rid of the stuttering completely.

How can it be done?

Comment: Please read the first section 'Sound or music?' of the [official documentation](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/audio-sounds.php). Basically you are using the wrong API.

Comment: Looking further at the API and at your situation, it seems you will need to create a custom `InputStream` that uses `mpg123_read` and pass that custom stream to `Music::openFromStream`.

Comment: Would be nice if the code was a [repro], so people coming here could learn something.